# MySQL: Fetch all rows where nested JSON value is in array of JSON values?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fetch all rows where a nested JSON value is in an array of values, but I'm getting : `Unknown column 'metadata' in 'where clause'`

SQL:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(eagerly_loaded_data, "$.Metadata") AS metadata 
FROM worker_items 
WHERE metadata IN ('metadata1', 'metadata2');
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: You cannot use output column alias in WHERE.

Comment: The column alias isn't visible to the `WHERE` clause.